# How can I count the amount of five letter words in a txt file using grep?

Tags: linux, count, grep, cpu-word

I'm not very good at linux, and am trying to use grep to count five letter words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `gnu awk` (due to mulitple characters in Record Selector) does count how many word have `5` letters.  It does ignore `.,` etc.

```
awk -v RS="[ .,?!]|\n" 'length($0)==5 {a++} END {print a}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
grep -o -w "\w\{5\}" your_file | wc -w
```

With `-o` only matched words will be printed, `-w` denotes that regex is searched as a word, `\w\{5\}` - regex string itself (matches 5 continuous word characters). So, with your_file containing

```
word1 word2 word3
long_word 123 word4
```

Output of `grep -o -w "\w\{5\}" your_file` will be

```
word1
word2
word3
word4
```

Piped `wc -w` just counts this.

**Note**: If you don't want to match all alphanumeric characters - replace `\w` meta-character by something more specific. For example `[a-z]` - lowercase English letters.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `c` flag to count, look for patterns containing five characters:

```
 $ cat file
 some text file containing many words and sentences.
 $ tr ' ' '\n' < file | grep -c '^[ \t]*[a-zA-Z]\{5\}[ \t]*$'
 1
```